# Can I have separate scales for hue, saturation, and lightness in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I'd like to experiment with using different components of hcl color to represent different aspects of my data in a plot. For example, representing a 2-dimensional vector using chroma for the magnitude and hue for the angle. Is there any way to do this in ggplot2, short of manually computing the color for each data point and then using `scale_color_identity`?

Comment: There are some tutorials and packages out there for bivariate color scales in ggplot2 which might be of some help. But I think that is the general approach...

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a [github package](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggchromatic/) at some point to do similar things, you might find it useful in your case. It's not field tested a lot, so beware the potential bugs.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggchromatic) # devtools::install_github("teunbrand/ggchromatic")

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = hcl_spec(h = Sepal.Width, c = Sepal.Length)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>